# Designing a Website in ASP.Net - User Login Design and Considerations

Tags: .net, asp.net, database, ms-access, login-script

I'm currently messing around in Access to develop a website, or I should say - develop the initial workings of a database system in an environment that I am familiar with.  As the .Net environment is the one I am most familiar with for developing, deploying the Access database into the more full-fledged SQL Server environment is a natural step.

Now comes the part with ASP.Net that I'm not so familiar with - reconciliating differences between how I am coding and designing my database with the default website project that ASP.Net provides for a basic multi-user website, from which I've noticed is a lot more thorough than any solution I could code up within a reasonable time-frame.

*However, this comes at a cost.  I have no inkling on how user data is stored within this environment or how to extend it within my own needs.*  I can make sample data up the wazoo on my laptop, but if I have no idea how to incorporate with a pre-existing framework, it is worthless to me.  *The reason why I have not considered this until now is the data I have been working on doesn't pertain to the users in a direct fashion.*

Anyone have experience designing websites that use ASP.Net and maintain user access?  **What problems, issues, and design considerations might I need to concern myself when developing a multi-user website with ASP.Net in addition to my data?**

Comment: I think you need to look in to extending the MembershipUser and MembershipProvider classes. _(See [extending Membership Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730%28VS.80%29.aspx) [MSDN])_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read this article "ASP.NET 2.0 Membership, Roles, Forms Authentication, and Security Resources"

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/24/ASP.NET-2.0-Membership_2C00_-Roles_2C00_-Forms-Authentication_2C00_-and-Security-Resources-.aspx